# r mirt error in UseMethod("itemfit") - no applicable method

Tags: r

I'm running the following r script and getting the following error message with either itemfit() or personfit()

```
    model_r <- mirt(data = dat,
                    model = 1,
                    itemtype = "Rasch")
    itemfit(model_r)
```

console message:

> Error in UseMethod("itemfit"):
> no applicable method for 'itemfit' applied to an object of class "c('SingleGroupClass', 'AllModelClass')"